# Getting a Collection Report of User in Angular and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to ask for help with this one.

I'm just still planning on this one so I don't have a code yet available,

Supposedly I have 5 users who access a POS transaction page, each of them transacts at different locations.

I was able to store each of their transactions in a firestoreCollection called transactions, however, I would like to know how to implement a collection report for each individual detail of their transactions for their end of day reports just by choosing their user name and collection date.

for example:

Cashier 1

Total Cash
Total Discount
Cashier Location

Cashier 2

Total Cash
Total Discount
Cashier Location

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't have any built in aggregation operators. Your options are limited to either aggregating at query time, or aggregating at write time.

Aggregating when you read the data to display it, is typically easy to do and works well for small data sets, but can quickly become slow and expensive as you have more data.

Aggregating the data when you're writing it to the database is initially harder to start with, but makes subsequent reading of the totals trivial and cheap.

Which one to use is a very common trade-off in NoSQL databases, where you often trade complexity at write time for faster, cheaper, and more scalable reads.

For more on this, I recommend:

- The Firebase documentation on [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation)
- The Firebase documentation on [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters)
- The [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) video series